# How to send an email from @example.com using the Google SMTP on Thunderbird?

Tags: email, smtp, thunderbird

I bought a virtual private server (VPS) and a domain name "example.com".

I installed and configured this on my VPS:

- an operating system (Debian 11)
- a web server (Apache)
- a mail server (Postfix)
- a DNS (BIND)

I tested my DNS with https://intodns.com/ and my mail server with https://mxtoolbox.com/ and everything is OK.

My VPS is working:

- I can go to my website by typing "example.com" in Firefox
- I can receive mails sent to "yugiohjcj@example.com" (I see them in my Postfix log, then I forward them to my yugiohjcj@gmail.com address using the ~/.forward file)
- I can send mails from "yugiohjcj@example.com" through the PHP function "mail" (I see them in my Postfix log)

However, I also need to send mails from "yugiohjcj@example.com" through my Thunderbird client.

As far as I know, my Postfix server does not provide remote SMTP authentication and cannot be used to send mails from "yugiohjcj@example.com" if I am not connected locally to the machine where Postfix is installed.

So, I would like to send mails from "yugiohjcj@example.com" through my Thunderbird client but using my usual Google SMTP.

I found how to set that in Thunderbird:

- Edit, Account Settings, yugiohjcj@gmail.com, Manage Identities..., Add...
- Your Name: Yugi Muto
- E-Mail Address: yugiohjcj@example.com
- Outgoing Server (SMTP): smtp.gmail.com
- Press the "OK" button

And now when I write a new mail, I can select my identity in the "From" field.

The problem is that I did a try and it was not the expected result.

I sent an e-mail to yugiohjcj2@gmail.com.

When I go to the yugiohjcj2@gmail.com mailbox, I see that the "From" field is "yugiohjcj@gmail.com" instead of "yugiohjcj@example.com".

How to have the correct "From" please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Remark: "example.com" is not my real domain name, it's just an example that is replacing the real value.